# Prism EventAggregator Buffering

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

The question is simple, really. Does the EventAggregator buffer events? Example: A single Subscriber listening for 2 different events, a GO and a NO-GO. Each event requires some work, database updates, notifying the UI etc. There could be as many as 64 publishers. The publishers work in near real-time so GO or NO-GOs could come very quickly. So can the Event Aggregator buffer these so the subscriber can process them in serial fashion.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the subscribe action is executed on the same thread as the event was published on. This means that the publisher won't be able to publish another event until the previous one has been handled by the subscriber. So the events are actually processed in serial fashion by default.

You can change this by specifying a `ThreadOption` when you subscribe:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<YourEventType>().Subscribe(s =>
            {
    //do something that make take a while but don't block the publisher...
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}, ThreadOption.BackgroundThread);
```

Comment: That will destroy the order of the events... no processing "them in serial fashion"

Comment: Read the answer again. They are published and retrieved on the same thread by default. It doesn't get any more "serial" than this.

Comment: "That" refers to the proposal of using `ThreadOption.BackgroundThread` to relieve the ui thread. That works, but it sacrifices event ordering.

Comment: Prism is an MVVM library. If you want to garantuee the that the events are retrieved in the same order as they are published you could for example use a BlockingCollection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx. Add the events from the collection from one thread and subscribe from another one. The event aggregator is just an event aggregator...

Comment: Exactly, he probably should go for a real message bus.

Comment: Thanks! You brought me full circle as my original thought was a task sitting on a BC processing the event. I like the Pub/Sub and event aggregation but I was not sure it was well suited for this application. I do use Pub/Sub for updating some VMs but that does not have the high throughput required.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle events in original order using [EventLoopScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.eventloopscheduler%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from [Reactive Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/). EventLoopScheduler will handle event publications in single background thread. It will not stop publisher's threads after calling of "Schedule" method

```
EventLoopScheduler eventLoopScheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();

eventAggregator.GetEvent<YourEventType>().Subscribe(s =>
{
    eventLoopScheduler.Schedule(() =>
    {
        //handler
    });
});
```

As for me, I use MessageBus from ReactiveUI instead of EventAggregator, because it can take IScheduler as argument and can remember last event payload after unsubscription.

Comment: I like this as well as I had not heard of Reactive Extensions so I have started to look at it and may find a new arrow to add to my quiver.